# Know when a view is reloaded via ajax

Tags: views, ajax, datetime

I have a year calendar view (loaded programmatically within the parent template) where the paging is done via ajax.

When I click on the navigation links (i.e 2013 / 2015) the template for the parent view is reloaded via ajax into a container div, by Drupal.  But this is undesirable as it resets things which could have dynamically changed.

Ideally I'd like just the child calendar view reloaded. However, I can live with the parent view being reloaded if I can determine (by looking at the arguments passed, or some other method) whether it's being loaded because of a click on the nav buttons.

So how can a template know it's being reloaded via ajax?  Preferably finding the "arguments" passed in the ajax call.

Or..  How can I make sure that JUST the child view is reloaded, not the parent.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `request_uri()` in a preprocess function?

Comment: Thanks Clive, the request URI doesn't help here, as the AJAX uses _POST.  However, I've spent far too long trying to make this work, so I've turned off ajax, and now examine the URI in order to display the view(s) correctly.